# Logic circuit truth table help

Tags: digital-logic

A manufacturing plant needs to have a horn sound to signal quitting time. The horn should be activated when either of the following conditions is met:
1. It’s after 5 o’clock and all machines are shut down.
2. It’s Friday, the production run for the day is complete, and all machines are shut down.
Design a logic circuit that will control the horn.(hint to use four logic input variables to represent various conditions,for example A will be HIGH only when the time of the day is 5 o'clock or later)
i just need the truth table explained. like what else should be high or low for me to get my truth table done?
Please explain that and help me!
Thank you
please note that it is FOUR input variables. I need help with my truth table filled please?

Answer (score 1):

The nice part about a theoretical problem like this is that you get to choose the logic states of your inputs and outputs. The goal should then be to choose them such that you minimixe the complexity of the logic.

Start by identifying each input by asking yourself what factors control when the horn must sound. Don't worry about their interaction yet, just what input data you need.

Once you have the inputs cataloged, you can see that you have only one output to the horn. Because of the way the problem is written, you can choose if a high or low output causes the horn to sound (normal or inverted output).

Now that you have a catalog of inputs and outputs, reread the description again. Wherever it says "and", put an AND gate between those inputs.

Now will will find that you have a couple of AND gates, the output of which from any one should sound the horn. Another way of saying that is this gate's output OR this gate's output should sound the horn. Complete the circuit with this type of gate.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems seems to be "how to make a truth table", let's make it through an example.

I have an oven alarm that has to ring in two conditions: 1 When the food is cooked and there is still gas in the tank. 2 There is no gas in the tank but the food is not cooked yet. 
First you have to identify your conditions and label them:
A: Food is cooked 
B: There is gas on the tank

Then you build your table of truth by drawing all the possible combinations of your conditions:

```
 A | B 
 F | F - >
 F | T - >
 T | F - >
 T | T - >
```

Then you check in which conditions your output (the alarm) comes true (rings), in this case the alarm only rings when the food is cooked and there's gas on the tank, or, there's no gas in the tank but the food isn't cooked yet:

```
 A | B 
 F | F - > T
 F | T - > F
 T | F - > F
 T | T - > T
```

That's the final table of truth, with it you can check the combinations that put your output in true to see what logic circuitry you need.

Comment: Thank you so is this what the result of my question is supposed to be?  its 5 o'clock or later(A)
all the machines are shut down(B)
it is friday(C)
production is complete.(D)      A should be 1 and then B is zero so the output would be high when A=1 and B=0? then then C and D are both 1 the output should be one as well? Is it supposed to be that way? When A is 1 and B is 0 output=1 When C and D are 1 output=1

Comment: The result of your homework question not, since it asks you to "Design a logic circuit that will control the horn", so your answer should be something like: A&(B+~C)+~A or something like that. My answer is just how to create a table of truth (since your question was "i just need the truth table explained. like what else should be high or low for me to get my truth table done?") based on an example of two inputs, in your case, it should be with 4 inputs, but the procedure is the same.